# Azure Template - Level Jagged Array

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I currently have a variable in my template.json file that is an array of arrays.

```
[[item, item, item], [item], [item, item], ...]
```

The top array is created through a [copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-loops-and-scopes) action, with the inner arrays each being a step in that copy. Unfortunately, the format I need the data in is non-jagged.

```
[item, item, item, item, item, item, ...]
```

Basically I need to concat an arbitrarily length array of arrays, but I can't find a way to use Azure's [concat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-array#concat) function with an arbitrary number of arrays. Is there any way to merge the arrays together as I need?

Answer (score 0):

The concat method wouldn't actually do what you suggested, it would however combine the elements of two arrays(not an array within an array as you would like to). an example is available [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp)

You could however add a few lines and format the internal arrays by joining them, combining **isArray()** with a loop to check if the elements within your table is an array, and if it is,use :**join()** , Examples for join can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp)

Comment: I'm sorry, but do you have an example of how this is intended to work? I'm not sure how I'd put Javascript functions in the template.json file.

Comment: Not within the template, you could write an external script that does what was mentioned in before to get the format you specifically want. There isn't a specific function in the templates that does it from my knowledge.